# render templates for a specific route directly from the server

Tags: angularjs

when using routes in an angular.js application is it possible to render the template for a specific route directly from the server and then attach your controller to it?

For example, i have an application with a login screen and a screen which shows some content when the user is logged in.

- When the user isn't logged in and he opens the application it would be cool if i could render the template for the login route directly from the server and then attach the right controller to it. So that the user gets feedback directly and doesn't have to wait until angular.js is bootstrapped before the page shows anything.
- When the user is logged in and he opens the application i want to render the template for the content page directly from the server and then attach the controller to it as you would do when you don't use the routing from angular.js (with ng-controller for example). Some stuff on this page will be cloacked because it needs the controller attached to it before it shows anything useful.

I'm quiet new to angular, i just experimented a bit with angular.js and the routing api. But in my test application when i open it, it first shows nothing and then when angular is bootstrapped it renders the view for the "/" route. I want to show the view direcly because some of the information doesn't need the controller attached to it. Other things i can hide using ng-cloack or ng-bind. But this way it will be much cleaner.

Doesn anyone has an idea how to achieve this? If my explanation still is a bit unclear, let me know. I found it hard to explain this ...

kind regards,

Daan

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I never tried this solution, but I guess the controller template has not necessarily to be a static file.
You need to provide a path to your template, but it could be created dynamically.
For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.php', controller: 'LoginCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.when('/logout', {templateUrl: 'partials/logout.php', controller: 'LogoutCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
  }]);
```

login.php and logout.php must return a valide AngularJS template.
I never tried this, but it should work.
I don't know if this is the Angular way of doing things.

Comment: i also think this will work and i'll also need this. But the question above was more about when i do the initial page load of my app i want the template directly rendered into the ng-view of the page (on the server) ... and not wait until angular is bootstrapped before the template is placed into the ng-view of the page.

Comment: So why are you using a client-side library if you want to render the template on the server?

Comment: because i only want this on the initial page load, everything from there should be done client-side ... this is just to make it prettier when the client accidently refreshes the page or so ...

Comment: you can use ng-cloak to prevent template to be displayed before it is compiled. Otherwise you can use server-side scripts to compile your first page and then keep on using AngularJS. I don't think you can use AngularJS as server-side compiler. Perhaps with node.js you can do something similar, but I am totally unaware of a solution like this.